How to Determine the Low High Water Mark (LHWM) in Oracle DB?
How could one determine the position of the Low High Water Mark (LHWM) for a non-partitioned heap table segment in Oracle?
Note: Using Locally Managed Tablespaces (LMT) and Automatic Segment Space Management (ASSM) on Oracle 19c 19.23 Enterprise Edition on Red Hat.
EDIT: This question was posted on Database Administrators with more details.

This question belongs on [dba.se], as it has nothing to do with programming.

You could do block dumps of the bitmap blocks and inspect them. But why? This doesn't have any practical use.

I'm interested in knowing why this information would be useful, but anyway, you could see the data distribution by blocks via
SQL> create table t as select * from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL> select dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid), count(*)
  2  from t
  3  group by dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid)
  4  order by 1;

DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_BLOCK_NUMBER(ROWID)   COUNT(*)
------------------------------------ ----------
                               98731         66
                               98732         64
                               98733         62
...
...

or similar, and if needed, use DBA_EXTENTS to restrict this to the last extent, because thats where LHWM/HHWM are typically relevant.

Great point about focusing on the last extent.

Thank you for your insight.  I moved this question to Database Administrators with more details and an explanation of my motivation for asking this question.  I would be honored if we could continue the discussion there.

SELECT segment_name, segment_type, blocks, bytes, extents, partition_name
FROM dba_segments WHERE segment_name IN ( .... )
;

The LHWM is represented by the "blocks" column, and the HWM is represented by the "bytes" column.

bytes is simply blocks * the block size of the tablespace
